# Algoritmo Bubble Sort em Python

Tags: python

```
def bubble_sort(lista):
elementos = len(lista)-1
ordenado = False
while not ordenado:
    ordenado = True
    for i in range(elementos):
      if lista[i] > lista[i+1]:
           lista[i], lista[i+1] = lista[i+1],lista[i]
           ordenado = False        
    print(lista)
return lista
```

Imprimir assim
bubble_sort([5, 1, 4, 2])

[1, 5, 4, 2]

[1, 4, 5, 2]

[1, 4, 2, 5]

[1, 2, 4, 5]

deve devolver [1, 2, 4, 5]

Ele está imprimindo 
bubble_sort([5, 1, 4, 2])

[1, 4, 2, 5]

[1, 2, 4, 5]

[1, 2, 4, 5]

[1, 2, 4, 5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito seja mais um erro de identação:

Dessa forma saiu correto:

```
def bubble_sort(lista):
    elementos = len(lista)-1
    ordenado = False
    while not ordenado:
        ordenado = True
        for i in range(elementos):
            if lista[i] > lista[i+1]:
                lista[i], lista[i+1] = lista[i+1],lista[i]
                ordenado = False        
                print(lista)
    return lista
```

Minha saida foi:

```
>>> def bubble_sort(lista):
...     elementos = len(lista)-1
...     ordenado = False
...     while not ordenado:
...         ordenado = True
...         for i in range(elementos):
...             if lista[i] > lista[i+1]:
...                 lista[i], lista[i+1] = lista[i+1],lista[i]
...                 ordenado = False        
...                 print(lista)
...     return lista
... 
>>> bubble_sort([5, 1, 4, 2])
[1, 5, 4, 2]
[1, 4, 5, 2]
[1, 4, 2, 5]
[1, 2, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Atente-se que Python é uma linguagem que exige de seu desenvolvedor atenção na identação. Seu possível problema está ocorrendo no uso do comando com a possível identação.

> print(lista)

Comment: Obrigado, eu testei a indentação.

Answer (score 0):

É importante manter a semântica do programa e evitar algo que não faça sentido como:

```
while not ordenado:
  ordenado = True
```

Uma implementação simples em python:

```
def bubble_sort(ulist):
for j in range(len(ulist) - 1):
    for i in range(len(ulist) - 1):
        if ulist[i] > ulist[i+1]:
            ulist[i], ulist[i+1] = ulist[i+1], ulist[i]
return ulist
```

Comment: E essa seria uma implementação do bubbles sort?